# What to do in between chess matches?

Tags: tournament

At a 2-day tournament, rounds can have two hours - sometimes three - before the next match.

What is a good way to spend this time? Should it involve chess? Carlsen, for example, spends his off-days during the WCC by playing tennis.

Comment: @Brian Towers how in the world is this off-topic?

Comment: This has nothing to do with chess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important advice in this situation is probably that you should avoid straining yourself mentally whatever you do. Try to rest inbetween rounds and clear your head, and if you want to spend your free time on chess it should absolutely not be you trying to challenge yourself with difficult positions before the next round; solving difficult chess exercises inbetween rounds will only serve to give you mental fatigue, which will seriously impair your chances in the next round.

It is up to each individual to decide what to do between rounds, but good activities may include casual walks, listening to some nice music, talking to friends, etc. Even some chess activities can be done if they're not mentally straining; for instance one may play some casual blitz/bughouse games, or solve some **extraordinarily easy** tactical exercises before the next round as a warm-up.

Some things that should be avoided between games is stressful activities, difficult chess exercises, and over-eating (if there is a lunch break between rounds, for instance). Stressful activities and difficult chess exercises will wear you down before the next game, while over-eating will also result in your body taking unnecessary strain from digesting food, which could potentially throw your body off balance before the game.

So, in essence, between rounds you should focus on letting yourself recover from the previous game so that you are in as good a shape as possible for the coming rounds, maximizing your chances of success.